# NTH:CHILD not being recognized on some site pages

Tags: css

I am having an issue getting my NTH:CHILD code to read on a certain page. It was working and now that I check my archive pages it will not recognize the code. It is working on the homepage.

http://sc103.radiobrandbuilders.com

But if you check an archive page the thumbnails don't recognize the CSS.  It is suppose to remove the margin from every 2nd image so it will display on one line.

http://sc103.radiobrandbuilders.com/tag/mick-jagger/

Here is the current code I am using in the stylesheet:

```
.main-page-thumbnail:nth-child(2n+0) {
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

It was working when I first did it and now I can't figure out why the archive page won't read from the stylesheet.

Thanks.

Comment: Include relevant code in the question itself. Links to live pages become useless after the problem has been fixed or the pages have otherwise been changed. We want questions and answers to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for the heads up on how you want questions to be asked in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is different, in your "non archive" page you have something like

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
   <div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
   <div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
   <div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
   <div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
</div>
```

But in your archive section your "main-page-thumbnails" do not share the same parent (they are currently wrapped in `<article>` elements) so strictly speaking they are always "the first child" of their parents.

Comment: P.S. if you remove the `<article>` using the developer tools, the `.main-page-thumbnail` will inherit the CSS.

Comment: Maybe you will need to define your css selector to be something like `article:nth-child(2n+0) .main-page-thumbnail`

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is not consistent between the two pages. In order for the `:nth-child()` selector to work the child elements must be siblings.

For example, on the homepage, the markup looks like this (works):

```
<div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
<div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
<div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
```

Your inner page the markup looks like this (doesn't work):

```
<article>
    <div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
</article>
<article>
    <div class="main-page-thumbnail">...</div>
</article>
```

You can either change your markup on your inner pages or add a class like:

```
article:nth-child(2n+1) > .main-page-thumbnail {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```